# Jquery Datatables - input search and select search combined on same thead

Tags: jquery, datatable, daterangepicker

i'm trying to mixed select input filter AND input filter on the same header.

I've create a second header where i put all my filter input. 
I've put here daterangepicker and input filter.

My problem is that i can't find the way to set my select input filter on the same row. (you can see that select input stay on first header, i want them with the other input filter on the second header).

I need help !

see my code here (it may be ugly but i works till here...) :

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {


//DATATABLE
//To display datatable without search and page length select, and to still have pagination work, instantiate like so
var oTable=$('#table_id').dataTable({

    "sDom":"tp",
    "pageLength": 10,
    "pagination":true,
        // Date Sorting
    columnDefs: [
       { type: 'date-eu', targets: ([1,6])}
     ],
     //// order table onload
"order": [[ 1, 'desc' ]],
    });
//DATE RANGE
//set global vars that are set by daterange picker, to be used by datatable
var startdate;
var enddate;

////////// Filter search date on column 6

//instantiate datepicker and choose your format of the dates
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           "Aujourd'hui": [moment(), moment()],
           'Hier': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Les 7 derniers jours': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Les 30 derniers jours': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'Ce mois-ci': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Le mois dernier': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
,
    "opens": "right",
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'

},
function(start, end,label) {
// Parse it to a moment
var s = moment(start.toISOString());
var e = moment(end.toISOString());
startdate = s.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
enddate = e.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
});

//Filter the datatable on the datepicker apply event with reportage 1
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
startdate=picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
enddate=picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
if(startdate!=undefined){
// 1 here is the column where my dates are.
//Convert to YYYY-MM-DD format from DD/MM/YYYY
var coldate = aData[1].split("/");
var d = new Date(coldate[2], coldate[1]-1 , coldate[0]);
var date = moment(d.toISOString());
date =    date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

//Remove hyphens from dates
dateMin=startdate.replace(/-/g, "");
dateMax=enddate.replace(/-/g, "");
date=date.replace(/-/g, "");

//console.log(dateMin, dateMax, date);

// run through cases to filter results
if ( dateMin == "" && date <= dateMax){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin =="" && date <= dateMax ){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin <= date && "" == dateMax ){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin <= date && date <= dateMax ){
return true;
}

// all failed
return false;
}
}
);
oTable.fnDraw();
});


////////// Filter search input date on column 6

//instantiate datepicker and choose your format of the dates
$('#reportrange2').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           "Aujourd'hui": [moment(), moment()],
           'Hier': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Les 7 derniers jours': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Les 30 derniers jours': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'Ce mois-ci': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Le mois prochain': [moment().add(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().add(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
,
    "opens": "right",
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'

},
function(start, end,label) {
// Parse it to a moment
var s = moment(start.toISOString());
var e = moment(end.toISOString());
startdate = s.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
enddate = e.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
});

//Filter the datatable on the datepicker apply event with reportage 2
$('#reportrange2').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
startdate=picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
enddate=picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
if(startdate!=undefined){
// 1 here is the column where my dates are.
//Convert to YYYY-MM-DD format from DD/MM/YYYY
var coldate = aData[6].split("/");
var d = new Date(coldate[2], coldate[1]-1 , coldate[0]);
var date = moment(d.toISOString());
date =    date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

//Remove hyphens from dates
dateMin=startdate.replace(/-/g, "");
dateMax=enddate.replace(/-/g, "");
date=date.replace(/-/g, "");

//console.log(dateMin, dateMax, date);

// run through cases to filter results
if ( dateMin == "" && date <= dateMax){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin =="" && date <= dateMax ){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin <= date && "" == dateMax ){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin <= date && date <= dateMax ){
return true;
}

// all failed
return false;
}
}
);
oTable.fnDraw();
});


////////// Setup - add a filter input to column 3,4,5 second Header .filter cell

    $('#table_id .filters .FilterinputSearch').each( function () {
        var title = $('#table_id thead .FilterinputSearch').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="recherche '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns([3,4,5]).eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', $('.filters th')[colIdx] ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );


    } );



////////// Setup - add a filter select input to column 0,2 

            $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([0,2]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );

} );
```

**EDIT**

I've edit my JSFIDDLE with only inut text search and select input search.
select works but unfortunatly not the text input...

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5qknp86r/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `opens: left` in the last daterange picker

https://jsfiddle.net/5qknp86r/5/

```
 $('#reportrange2').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           "Aujourd'hui": [moment(), moment()],
           'Hier': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Les 7 derniers jours': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Les 30 derniers jours': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'Ce mois-ci': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Le mois prochain': [moment().add(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().add(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
    "opens": "left",
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'

},
```

Comment: hello,
yes right ! it looks better like that ! what do you think about my code to display text input search (columns 1,3,4,5) and select input search (column 0, 2) ?

Comment: It's fine, with bootstrap classnames. However, you are asking for an opinion, and in stackoverflow we only help to programation issues. All opinions are out of the topic, in other words, are offtopic.

Comment: Have you tak a look at my JSFIDDLE demo i've indicated on my first post ?
I have a error on table initializing and also i want to combine text input search and select input search. However i also appreciate your opinion !

Comment: Yes, I've seen your fiddle and I edited it to answer you. I don't know how you are asking me

Comment: see my answer up there ;)

Comment: In your updated fiddle there's no errors, but I see that input doesn't have the search functionality. Maybe you need to put a classname to identify it (`<input type="text" class="searchinput" placeholder="Search '+title+'">` and then the script `$('.searchinput').on('change', function() { //your search code });`